# How to make scroll to top button appear only when you have started scrolling down in angular without jquery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll

I'm trying to do it using a custom directive for that element and manipulate in the link function but I don't know how to proceed. Can we do it using pure javascript or any other library except jquery since people say 'no jquery in angular apps please' for some reason.

Comment: please add what yah got so far

Answer (score 0):

Found out Javascript has some inbuilt functions like .onscroll, .scrollY, .scroll which can be used to achieve the aforementioned functionality. I think a search into javascript in-built functions will get most of the stuff done before moving onto jquery.